# Pandas: Get max value of a group ONLY if the value satisfies given conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

I have a large df:[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asw4WW2nEbsaiKIOO5KVk-L6cV63wg?e=eni7dk).
The data is grouped by col, row, year, No, potveg and total.  I am trying to get the max value of 'total' column in a specific year of a group **ONLY** if its 'Possible' value is TRUE. If the max 'total' value is FALSE, then get the second max value, and so on.

If all the values of the 'possible' column in a specific year group = false,  then I want to pick the max out of those so that I don't skip any years.

i.e., for the dataset below:

```
col   row   year    No  potveg  total   Possible
                        
-125 42.5   2015    1   9       697.3   FALSE
            2015    2   13      535.2   TRUE
            2015    3   15      82.3    TRUE
            2016    1   9       907.8   TRUE
            2016    2   13      137.6   FALSE
            2016    3   15      268.4   TRUE
            2017    1   9       961.9   FALSE
            2017    2   13      74.2    TRUE
            2017    3   15      248     TRUE
            2018    1   9       937.9   TRUE
            2018    2   13      575.6   TRUE
            2018    3   15      215.5   FALSE
-135 70.5   2015    1   8       697.3   FALSE
            2015    2   10      535.2   TRUE
            2015    3   19      82.3    TRUE
            2016    1   8       907.8   TRUE
            2016    2   10      137.6   FALSE
            2016    3   19      268.4   TRUE
            2017    1   8       961.9   FALSE
            2017    2   10      74.2    TRUE
            2017    3   19      248     TRUE
            2018    1   8       937.9   TRUE
            2018    2   10      575.6   TRUE
            2018    3   19      215.5   FALSE
```

The output would be:

```
col   row   year    No  potveg  total   Possible
                        
-125 42.5   2015    2   13      535.2   TRUE
            2016    1   9       907.8   TRUE
            2017    3   15      248     TRUE
            2018    1   9       937.9   TRUE
            
-135 70.5   2015    2   10      535.2   TRUE
            2016    1   8       907.8   TRUE
            2017    3   19      248     TRUE
            2018    1   8       937.9   TRUE
```

I tried:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df.groupby(['col','row','year']).agg({'total':'max'}).reset_index(), 
               df, 
               on=['col', 'row', 'year', 'total'])
```

But that only selects the max value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your new provided dataset, this is the solution I came up with.  Not 100% sure it's what you're after, I re-read the question and I think it's not actually what you're after but I'll put it here anyway.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Separate out the true and false possibilities.
true_df = df[df['Possible'] == True]
false_df = df[df['Possible'] == False]

# Group the true and the false values by their max 'total' values.
truth_aggregated_df = pd.merge(true_df.groupby(['col', 'row', 'year']).agg({'total': 'max'}).reset_index(),
                               true_df,
                               on=['col', 'row', 'year', 'total'])
false_aggregated_df = pd.merge(false_df.groupby(['col', 'row', 'year']).agg({'total': 'max'}).reset_index(),
                               false_df,
                               on=['col', 'row', 'year', 'total'])

# Iterate through the false_aggregated_df to create a list on indexes in the where the following conditions are met:
#   the indexes in the list will have their 'col', 'row', 'No' and 'potveg' in the 'truth_aggregated_df'.
#   the indexes in the list will NOT have their 'year' in the 'truth_aggregated_df'.
# This way, we'll collect the indexes where a year is not represented for a specific 'col', 'row', 'No' and 'potveg'
# combination
false_indexes_to_keep = list()
for false_index, false_row in false_aggregated_df.iterrows():
    false_col_in_true_df = false_row['col'] in truth_aggregated_df['col'].values
    false_row_in_true_df = false_row['row'] in truth_aggregated_df['row'].values
    false_no_in_true_df = false_row['No'] in truth_aggregated_df['No'].values
    false_potveg_in_true_df = false_row['potveg'] in truth_aggregated_df['potveg'].values
    if false_col_in_true_df is False or false_row_in_true_df is False or false_no_in_true_df is False \
            or false_potveg_in_true_df is False:
        continue
    # If we know we have a 'col', 'row, 'No' and 'potveg' that's represented in the truth_aggregated_df
    # we next need to check if the truth_aggregated_df is missing any years that exists in the `false_row` being
    # iterated on.  If so, we make note of the corresponding false index.
    truth_aggregated_df_subset = truth_aggregated_df[(truth_aggregated_df['col'] == false_row['col']) &
                                                     (truth_aggregated_df['row'] == false_row['row']) &
                                                     (truth_aggregated_df['No'] == false_row['No']) &
                                                     (truth_aggregated_df['potveg'] == false_row['potveg'])]
    false_year_not_in_true_df = false_row['year'] not in truth_aggregated_df_subset['year'].values
    if false_col_in_true_df and false_row_in_true_df and false_no_in_true_df and false_potveg_in_true_df and \
            false_year_not_in_true_df:
        false_indexes_to_keep.append(false_index)

# Create the subset of the false_aggregated_df using the list we just made
false_subset_df = false_aggregated_df[false_aggregated_df.index.isin(false_indexes_to_keep)]

concat_df = pd.concat([truth_aggregated_df, false_subset_df])
concat_df = concat_df.sort_values(by=['col', 'row', 'year', 'potveg', 'No'])
print(concat_df)
```

That output dataframe will contain the max 'total' value for each year for each 'col', 'row', 'No' and 'potveg' combination.  It will fill in the missing 'col', 'row', 'No' and 'potveg' combinations for each years from the dataframe that contains the `False` values in the 'Possible' column.

There's almost certainly a better way, but this is the way that I think is the most simple.  Generally iterating through a dataframe is a bad idea.

Comment: This removes some years since the 'possible' for all the values in those years =  false. If all the values of the 'possible' column in a specific year group = false,  then I want to pick the max out of those so that I don't skip any years.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification.  Always a good idea to account for the edge cases in your dataset, if it's a specific edge case you're hoping to avoid.  In the original data I don't think that outcome you've specified can occur.  I've updated my question to match the need though.

Comment: For some reason, this fails to produce the expected output on my data set it still skips years. I have tried several versions of your implementation nothing seems to work. I was thinking about splitting based on true or false like you did.  Then selecting the max value of the 'total' column in a specific year. for both dfs.  Then comparing the two dfs and inserting missing years on the true df from the false df. But I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Feel free to add more data to your original question if you want.  My answer gets your expected output & also works in the modified sample data I altered to test for the initial edge case I missed.  Without seeing more data I can't really provide insight as to why this answer doesn't hold to your larger data set.  I'd imagine it'd be an issue with joining, maybe the subset of keys (col, row, year) aren't actually a primary key when combined together.  My answer does rely on that being the case.

Comment: here is the dataset I am using please have a look  [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asw4WW2nEbsaiKIOO5KVk-L6cV63wg?e=eni7dk)

Comment: Okay, I think I have it, but I just re-read your question and I'm not really sure anymore... this will get the max total value for each row combination if the 'Possible' value is true.  If there is a missing row combination for a 'year', it will instead get the max total value for that row combination from the dataframe where the 'Possible' values are false.

Comment: So this gets close to the desired result. The only issue is that in the years that the max value = False. It retains the max False value and appends the next max True value in the year group. Instead of only outputting only the next max True value in the year group.  See the example below.

Comment: `-125.0,42.5,2024,893.0,1,9,True                                                                                                                                                                                        
-125.0,42.5,2025,899.2,1,9,False                                                                                             
-125.0,42.5,2025,232.2,2,13,True                                                                                                              
-125.0,42.5,2026,896.0,1,9,True                      
-125.0,42.5,2027,871.9,1,9,True`

Comment: in the year 2025, it retained both. Instead of just picking the True value.  I have tried solving this by: `pd.merge(data.groupby(['col','row','year']).agg({'total':'min'}).reset_index(),  data, on=['col', 'row', 'year', 'total'])` On the assumption that where the max 'total' is False the next True 'total' will always be  less  than max 'total'. But this is not always true.

Comment: By the way, if everything works well, the final df should be approx  **size (33942,7)***

Answer (score 2):

You can do `sort_values` first then `groupby` wit `head`

```
out = df.sort_values(['Possible','total'], ascending = [False,False]).groupby(['col','row','year']).head(1)
```

Comment: How I do go back to the original sort?  `.sort_values` doesn't seem to do it for my dataset.