# Filter main df and get max value of a group ONLY if another column's value satisfies given conditions (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a large df (over 100,000 rows). The data is grouped by col, row, year, No, potveg and total. I am trying to get the max value of 'total' column in a specific year group ONLY if its 'Possible' value is TRUE. If the max 'total' value is FALSE, then get the second max value, and so on.

If all the values of the 'possible' column in a specific year group = false, then I want to pick the max out of the 'FALSE' so that I don't skip any years and avoid duplicates.

i.e., for the dataset below:

```
col   row   year    No  potveg  total   Possible
                        
-125 42.5   2015    1   9       697.3   FALSE
            2015    2   13      535.2   TRUE
            2015    3   15      82.3    TRUE
            2016    1   9       907.8   TRUE
            2016    2   13      137.6   FALSE
            2016    3   15      268.4   TRUE
            2017    1   9       961.9   FALSE
            2017    2   13      74.2    TRUE
            2017    3   15      248     TRUE
            2018    1   9       937.9   TRUE
            2018    2   13      575.6   TRUE
            2018    3   15      215.5   FALSE
-135 70.5   2015    1   8       697.3   FALSE
            2015    2   10      535.2   TRUE
            2015    3   19      82.3    TRUE
            2016    1   8       907.8   TRUE
            2016    2   10      137.6   FALSE
            2016    3   19      268.4   TRUE
            2017    1   8       961.9   FALSE
            2017    2   10      74.2    TRUE
            2017    3   19      248     TRUE
            2018    1   8       937.9   TRUE
            2018    2   10      575.6   TRUE
            2018    3   19      215.5   FALSE
            2019    1   8       937.9   FALSE
            2019    2   10      575.6   FALSE
            2019    3   19      215.5   FALSE
```

The output would be:

```
col   row   year    No  potveg  total   Possible
                        
-125 42.5   2015    2   13      535.2   TRUE
            2016    1   9       907.8   TRUE
            2017    3   15      248     TRUE
            2018    1   9       937.9   TRUE
            
-135 70.5   2015    2   10      535.2   TRUE
            2016    1   8       907.8   TRUE
            2017    3   19      248     TRUE
            2018    1   8       937.9   TRUE
            2019    1   8       937.9   FALSE
```

I tried the solution provided in this  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73410616/pandas-get-max-value-of-a-group-only-if-the-value-satisfies-given-conditions), but that doesn't give the correct output.

Any ideas:

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with a double [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

1. We group by `['col','row','year','Possible']` and get the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for column `total`. At the end, we sort the result on `Possible` in descending order. This will put all idxmax values (now in `total`) with `True` in `Possible` first.
2. Now, we can apply a second `groupby`, this time only on `['col','row','year']` and simply get the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html).

So:

```
idx = df.groupby(
    ['col','row','year','Possible'], as_index=False)['total']\
    .idxmax().sort_values('Possible', ascending=False)['total']

result = df.iloc[idx].groupby(['col','row','year']).first()

print(result)

                No  potveg  total  Possible
col  row  year                             
-135 70.5 2015   2      10  535.2      True
          2016   1       8  907.8      True
          2017   3      19  248.0      True
          2018   1       8  937.9      True
          2019   1       8  937.9     False
-125 42.5 2015   2      13  535.2      True
          2016   1       9  907.8      True
          2017   3      15  248.0      True
          2018   1       9  937.9      True
```

In the process, the order of the rows is affected. We can re-establish the original order by using [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) based on the original `df` with index there set to `['col','row','year']` and getting rid of the duplicates first. Like so:

```
orig_index = df.set_index(['col','row','year']).index.drop_duplicates()

result_reordered = result.reindex(orig_index)

print(result_reordered)

                No  potveg  total  Possible
col  row  year                             
-125 42.5 2015   2      13  535.2      True
          2016   1       9  907.8      True
          2017   3      15  248.0      True
          2018   1       9  937.9      True
-135 70.5 2015   2      10  535.2      True
          2016   1       8  907.8      True
          2017   3      19  248.0      True
          2018   1       8  937.9      True
          2019   1       8  937.9     False
```

---

Data used:

```
data = {'col': {0: -125, 1: -125, 2: -125, 3: -125, 4: -125, 5: -125, 
                6: -125, 7: -125, 8: -125, 9: -125, 10: -125, 11: -125, 
                12: -135, 13: -135, 14: -135, 15: -135, 16: -135, 
                17: -135, 18: -135, 19: -135, 20: -135, 21: -135, 
                22: -135, 23: -135, 24: -135, 25: -135, 26: -135}, 
        'row': {0: 42.5, 1: 42.5, 2: 42.5, 3: 42.5, 4: 42.5, 5: 42.5, 
                6: 42.5, 7: 42.5, 8: 42.5, 9: 42.5, 10: 42.5, 11: 42.5, 
                12: 70.5, 13: 70.5, 14: 70.5, 15: 70.5, 16: 70.5, 
                17: 70.5, 18: 70.5, 19: 70.5, 20: 70.5, 21: 70.5, 
                22: 70.5, 23: 70.5, 24: 70.5, 25: 70.5, 26: 70.5},
        'year': {0: 2015, 1: 2015, 2: 2015, 3: 2016, 4: 2016, 5: 2016, 
                 6: 2017, 7: 2017, 8: 2017, 9: 2018, 10: 2018, 11: 2018, 
                 12: 2015, 13: 2015, 14: 2015, 15: 2016, 16: 2016, 
                 17: 2016, 18: 2017, 19: 2017, 20: 2017, 21: 2018, 
                 22: 2018, 23: 2018, 24: 2019, 25: 2019, 26: 2019}, 
        'No': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 
               9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 3, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3, 15: 1, 16: 2, 
               17: 3, 18: 1, 19: 2, 20: 3, 21: 1, 22: 2, 23: 3, 24: 1, 
               25: 2, 26: 3}, 
        'potveg': {0: 9, 1: 13, 2: 15, 3: 9, 4: 13, 5: 15, 6: 9, 
                   7: 13, 8: 15, 9: 9, 10: 13, 11: 15, 12: 8, 13: 10, 
                   14: 19, 15: 8, 16: 10, 17: 19, 18: 8, 19: 10, 20: 19, 
                   21: 8, 22: 10, 23: 19, 24: 8, 25: 10, 26: 19}, 
        'total': {0: 697.3, 1: 535.2, 2: 82.3, 3: 907.8, 4: 137.6, 
                  5: 268.4, 6: 961.9, 7: 74.2, 8: 248.0, 9: 937.9, 
                  10: 575.6, 11: 215.5, 12: 697.3, 13: 535.2, 14: 82.3, 
                  15: 907.8, 16: 137.6, 17: 268.4, 18: 961.9, 19: 74.2, 
                  20: 248.0, 21: 937.9, 22: 575.6, 23: 215.5, 24: 937.9, 
                  25: 575.6, 26: 215.5}, 
        'Possible': {0: False, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: False, 
                     5: True, 6: False, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 
                     10: True, 11: False, 12: False, 13: True, 14: True, 
                     15: True, 16: False, 17: True, 18: False, 19: True, 
                     20: True, 21: True, 22: True, 23: False, 24: False, 
                     25: False, 26: False}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my extensive data set.  The rows are mixed up and not in order.

Comment: Updated the reordering method. Let me know if it works now. Another thing that occurred to me is that your col `"Possible"` seems to contain *strings* (indeed: `"TRUE" | "FALSE"`) rather than proper *booleans* (`True | False`). If so, this shouldn't affect the outcome in this particular case. Nonetheless, I would advise you to change them into actual *booleans* for future calculations. You can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for this: `df['Possible'] = df['Possible'].map({'TRUE': True,'FALSE': False})`.

Comment: Works, thanks. and you were right I had to convert the True, and False values to bools.